# regex pattern for serial-number input

Tags: regex, constraints, check-constraints, serial-number

Someone can help me pls I have a serial-number input and I need the expression regex to validate this input [ex: 11-22-33333] number of character max=11, I added this pattern but it doesn't work

```
"pattern": "^[0-9]{2}*-?[0-9]{2}*-?[0-9]{5}$",
```

Comment: Your regex seems correct. What issue are you facing exactly and what language you are using?

Comment: Try removing the asterix after the quantifier like `{2}`

Comment: i using a Json language,th problem is if i insert a correct serial number exp: 11-22-33333 the numbre is not accepted

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify the regexp flavor (java? bash? sed? python? php?), I write here the most compatible expression:

```
"^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}$"
```

https://regex101.com/r/2xGgL1/1/

Hope this helps

Comment: @chaima Please visit the link and you'll see it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
"purchase-1_serialNumber": {
  "extra_form_type": "text",
  "options": {
    "label": "Indiquez le n° de série:*",
    "pattern": "^[0-9]{2}*-?[0-9]{2}*-?[0-9]{5}$",
    "required": 1,
    "disabled": "0",
    "read_only": "0",
    "attr": {
      "title": "Ce numéro est composé de 9 chiffres séparés par 2 tirets (ex: 11-22-33333) que vous trouverez sur votre produit",
      "class": "input_serie",
      "placeholder": "N° de série*",
      "minlength": 11,
      "maxlength": 11
    },
    "label_attr": {
      "class": "label_serie"
    },
    "mapped": 1
  },
  "constraints": [
    {
      "extra_form_constraint": "not_blank",
      "options": {
        "message": "Merci de renseigner le n° de série."
      }
    },
    {
      "extra_form_constraint": "regex",
      "options": {
        "pattern": "^[0-9]{2}*-?[0-9]{2}*-?[0-9]{5}$",
        "match": true,
        "message": "Merci de renseigner correctement le N° de série."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please edit you question instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: @chaima attention, en français, ° signifie degré et, et n° ne peut pas être utilisé comme abréviation de numéro. (in french, ° means degree, and n° cant be used to shorten number)

Comment: @chaima json is not actual code, it’s just data. Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have this: `-?` in your original pattern, I'm guessing that what you might want is the number to either have both traces or none, hence I suggest the given regex:

```
^((\d\d-){2}|(\d\d){2})\d{5}$
```

**Demo:**

```js
const regex = /^((\d\d-){2}|(\d\d){2})\d{5}$/;

const testStrings = [
  '11-22-12345',
  '112212345',
  '1122-12345',
  '11-2212345',
  '1-12-12345',
  '12-12-123456'
];

testStrings.forEach(s => console.log(`${s} - ${regex.test(s)}`));
```